# make png image outline solid and uncolorable

Tags: image, flutter

I need to make a png image's outline completely opaque so if the user draws over the the lines won't get coloured.

This is my code:

```
      child: RepaintBoundary(
        key: globalKey,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: displayImage(context, widget.imagePath),
            ),
            CustomPaint(
              size: Size.infinite,
              painter: MyPainter(
                pointsList: points,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

And here's an image of what I've dont till now

[image]

In short the users wont be able to draw or color the black outlines

[Link to the full code:](https://pastebin.com/ipjt3ExG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your custom paint below your image to achieve that. If you are worried that by doing this all the gestures will be absorbed by the image widget and user might not be able to draw, just wrap your image widget with the `IgnorePointer` widget. Result will be like this :

```
child: RepaintBoundary(
        key: globalKey,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomPaint(
              size: Size.infinite,
              painter: MyPainter(
                pointsList: points,
              ),
            ),

            Center(
              child: IgnorePointer(ignoring: true,child: displayImage(context, widget.imagePath)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

IgnorePointer, as the name suggests will ignore any gestures occurred on it's child widget

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer but I IgnorePointer doesn't work and I need the users to color the hut but not the outlines